# How to get the HTTP response when the request stream was closed during transfer

Tags: c#, .net, http, tomcat, httpwebrequest

**TL;DR version**

When a transfer error occurs while writing to the request stream, I can't access the response, even though the server sends it.

---

**Full version**

I have a .NET application that uploads files to a Tomcat server, using `HttpWebRequest`. In some cases, the server closes the request stream prematurely (because it refuses the file for one reason or another, e.g. an invalid filename), and sends a 400 response with a custom header to indicate the cause of the error.

The problem is that if the uploaded file is large, the request stream is closed *before* I finish writing the request body, and I get an `IOException`:

> **Message**: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>   **InnerException**: `SocketException`: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

I can catch this exception, but then, when I call `GetResponse`, I get a `WebException` with the previous `IOException` as its inner exception, and a null `Response` property. **So I can never get the response, even though the server sends it** (checked with WireShark).

Since I can't get the response, I don't know what the actual problem is. From my application point of view, it looks like the connection was interrupted, so I treat it as a network-related error and retry the upload... which, of course, fails again.

How can I work around this issue and retrieve the actual response from the server? Is it even possible? To me, the current behavior looks like a bug in `HttpWebRequest`, or at least a severe design issue...

---

Here's the code I used to reproduce the problem:

```
var request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);
request.Method = "POST";
string filename = "foo\u00A0bar.dat"; // Invalid characters in filename, the server will refuse it
request.Headers["Content-Disposition"] = string.Format("attachment; filename*=utf-8''{0}", Uri.EscapeDataString(filename));
request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
request.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
request.ContentLength = 100 * 1024 * 1024;

// Upload the "file" (just random data in this case)
try
{
    using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
        new Random().NextBytes(buffer);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // here I get an IOException; InnerException is a SocketException
    Console.WriteLine("Error writing to stream: {0}", ex);
}

// Now try to read the response
try
{
    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", (int)response.StatusCode, response.StatusDescription);
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // here I get a WebException; InnerException is the IOException from the previous catch
    Console.WriteLine("Error getting the response: {0}", ex);
    var webEx = ex as WebException;
    if (webEx != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(webEx.Status); // SendFailure
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)webEx.Response;
        if (response != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", (int)response.StatusCode, response.StatusDescription);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No response");
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Additional notes:**

If I correctly understand the role of the `100 Continue` status, the server shouldn't send it to me if it's going to refuse the file. However, it seems that this status is controlled directly by Tomcat, and can't be controlled by the application. Ideally, I'd like the server not to send me `100 Continue` in this case, but according to my colleagues in charge of the back-end, there is no easy way to do it. So I'm looking for a client-side solution for now; but if you happen to know how to solve the problem on the server side, it would also be appreciated.

The app in which I encounter the issue targets .NET 4.0, but I also reproduced it with 4.5.

I'm not timing out. The exception is thrown long before the timeout.

I tried an async request. It doesn't change anything.

I tried setting the request protocol version to HTTP 1.0, with the same result.

---

Someone else has already filed a bug on Connect for this issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/779622/unable-to-get-servers-error-response-when-uploading-file-with-httpwebrequest

Comment: Hmm, I am still trying to figure out what is wrong here. However a server side solution that I can think of would be to implement a custom valve in the tomcat server for this case. I personally haven`t tried a valve yet, but just had a feeling that it would be a not so hard server side solution here.

Comment: Can you try and share the results of disabling the `Expect:100-Continue` header by means of: `ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;` before any requests are made? Also, as @jester points out: what HTTP version is the server using? The framework uses 1.1 by default.

Comment: @LeandroTaset, the server uses HTTP 1.1. Disabling Expect100Continue has no effect.

Comment: @jester, thanks, I talked to my server-side colleagues about valves; they will look into it.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: Sorry for the trial and error approach... I'm far from being an expert, but what about turning off Nagle's algorithm? I've read that it can badly impact small requests on HTTP. `ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;`.

Comment: @LeandroTaset, no it doesn't change anything either (and the problem occurs with large requests, not small ones). But anyway, none of these settings are likely to solve the root issue, which is the fact that HttpWebRequest just discards the response if it failed to upload the request body; it's a design flaw, and I'm looking for a workaround.

Comment: Have you tried using [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to check the response?

Comment: @AmanBaloch, not Fiddler, because it messes up the normal scenario; but using WireShark, I can see the response from the server (400 with a custom error header, as expected)

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Have you ever found a client-side workaround for this issue?

Comment: @DmitryKorolev not a good one. The client sends an id with the request, and if the request fails, it asks the server what went wrong for this request. It's ugly, but it works...

Comment: Can you change the client? Does other http client handle this with success?

Comment: @ilansch I no longer work on this project, so I can't change anything ;)
The issue exists with `HttpClient` and `HttpWebRequest`. I don't know of any other HTTP client for .NET.

Comment: of course, long time passed, my suggestion, as ugly as it is, switch library or create some proxy client with another library that does the actual upload, even not a .net one...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am out of ideas as to what can be a client side solution to your problem. But I still think the server side solution of using a custom tomcat valve can help here. I currently doesn`t have a tomcat setup where I can test this but I think a server side solution here would be along the following lines :

RFC section 8.2.3 clearly states :
Requirements for HTTP/1.1 origin servers:

```
  - Upon receiving a request which includes an Expect request-header
    field with the "100-continue" expectation, an origin server MUST
    either respond with 100 (Continue) status and continue to read
    from the input stream, or respond with a final status code. The
    origin server MUST NOT wait for the request body before sending
    the 100 (Continue) response. If it responds with a final status
    code, it MAY close the transport connection or it MAY continue
    to read and discard the rest of the request.  It MUST NOT
    perform the requested method if it returns a final status code.
```

So assuming tomcat confirms to the RFC, while in the custom valve you would have recieved the HTTP request header, but the request body would not be sent since the control is not yet in the servlet that reads the body.

So you can probably implement a custom valve, something similar to :

```
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Request;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Response;
import org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve;

public class CustomUploadHandlerValve extends ValveBase {

    @Override
    public void invoke(Request request, Response response) throws IOException, ServletException {
         HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
         String fileName = httpRequest.getHeader("Filename");  // get the filename or whatever other parameters required as per your code
         bool validationSuccess = Validate(); // perform filename check or anyother validation here
         if(!validationSuccess)
         {
             response = CreateResponse(); //create your custom 400 response here
             request.SetResponse(response);
             // return the response here
         }
         else
         {
             getNext().invoke(request, response); // to pass to the next valve/ servlet in the chain
         }
    }
    ...
}
```

DISCLAIMER : Again I haven`t tried this to success, need sometime and a tomcat setup to try it out ;).
Thought it might be a starting point for you.

Comment: Thanks; my colleague on the server-side is evaluating this idea. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: My colleague came up with a POC based on a valve, but it uses a different approach: it replaces the request and response with wrapper that control when `sendAcknowledgement` is called. It works, but the wrapper has to be adapted to each version of Tomcat, so it's hard to maintain...

Comment: Eventually my colleagues who work on the back-end decided against including the valve, because of the maintenance and deployment issues it introduces. The solution will be to issue a first request to check whether the file can be accepted, and then upload it. Not very elegant, but pragmatic... Anyhow, this is the best answer I received, so you get the bounty. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Thomas :) sorry I couldn't give you a better answer but happy that I could help.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. The server sends a response before the client end of the transmission of the request body, when I try to do async request. After a series of experiments, I found a workaround.
After the request stream has been received, I use reflection to check the private field `_CoreResponse` of the `HttpWebRequest`. If it is an object of class `CoreResponseData`, I take his private fields (using reflection): `m_StatusCode`, `m_StatusDescription`, `m_ResponseHeaders`, `m_ContentLength`. They contain information about the server's response!
In most cases, this hack works!

Comment: Just so you know, you can add code-formatting using the `back-trick` symbol :-)

Comment: Sometimes also referred to as `back-tick`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

What are you getting in the status code and response of the second exception not the internal exception?

If a WebException is thrown, use the Response and Status properties of the exception to determine the response from the server.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Please read the question carefully: I mentioned that the `Response` is null in the `WebException`. Otherwise I wouldn't have posted the question in the first place ;). `WebException.Response` is set only when the exception is caused by an error status code in the response, but in this case the response is just discarded.

Comment: Sorry about missing that but is the status code also empty?

Comment: The status code should be one of these http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383887.aspx

Comment: If I was to implement it I would've made 2 calls to the server one for just file creation and then sending file contents. This way you don't have to wait for a long time to find out there is a problem in file creation

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about the WebException.Status. As I said before, I don't have the response, so I don't have the status code...

Comment: Yes, I'm probably going to end up doing a first request to check whether I can upload, then do the actual upload.

Answer (score 1):

You are not saying what exactly version of Tomcat 7 you are using...

> checked with WireShark

What do you actually see with WireShark?

Do you see the status line of response?

Do you see the complete status line, up to CR-LF characters at its end?

Is Tomcat asking for authentication credentials (401), or it is refusing file upload for some other reason (first acknowledging it with 100 but then aborting it mid-flight)?

> The problem is that if the uploaded file is large, the request stream
>   is closed before I finish writing the request body, and I get an IOException:

If you do not want the connection to be closed but all the data transferred over the wire and swallowed at the server side, on Tomcat 7.0.55 and later it is possible to configure maxSwallowSize attribute on HTTP connector, e.g. maxSwallowSize="-1".

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

If you want to discuss Tomcat side of connection handling, you would better ask on the Tomcat users' mailing list,

http://tomcat.apache.org/lists.html#tomcat-users

At .Net side:

1. Is it possible to perform stream.Write() and request.GetResponse() simultaneously, from different threads?
2. Is it possible to performs some checks at the client side before actually uploading the file?

Comment: I didn't say it was Tomcat 7 ;) (but I believe it is; have to check with my colleagues). In Wireshark I see that the sever is sending a valid and complete response, with status line (error 400), headers and body. The file is refused for app-specific reasons (in my test, I specify a file name with invalid characters). I'm already authenticated.

Comment: I don't want Tomcat to swallow the data I'm sending (as I would be sending it for nothing). I want one of two things: 1. be able to read the response sent by the server, even if the upload was interrupted (client-side solution); 2. not receive the 100-Continue status if the server is going to refuse the file (server side solution)

Comment: Regarding your last two questions: 1. No, it wouldn't make sense; the server can't give me a meaningful response before the upload is complete (or interrupted). 2. Yes, it's a possible solution that I have already considered, but I'd rather avoid it unless I have no other choice.

Answer (score 0):

hmmm... i don't get it - that is EXACTLY why in many real-life scenarios large files are uploaded in chunks (and not as a single large file)

by the way: many internet servers have size limitations. for instance in tomcat that is representad by maxPostSize (as seen in this link: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html)

so tweaking the server configurations seems like the easy way, but i do think that the right way is to split the file to several requests

EDIT: replace Uri.EscapeDataString with HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode

```
 Uri.EscapeDataString(filename) // a problematic .net implementation
 HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode(filename) // the proper way to do it
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question... Splitting the file in chunks won't solve the problem I'm having now.

Comment: did you try to check the **maxPostSize** at your server? it limits the POST requests size in bytes

Comment: No, it doesn't. I can usually upload very large files without issues. And anyway, the problem I'm having also happens with relatively small files (a few MB).

Comment: i got something - it related with Uri.EscapeDataString as shown here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yangxind/archive/2006/11/09/don-t-use-net-system-uri-unescapedatastring-in-url-decoding.aspx. the tables in this acrticle show the difference between the standard encoding and .net implementation. maybe you can try to use HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode instead?

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the problem. The characters are properly encoded, but the server simply refuses certain characters (as per business rules). But anyway, it's beside the point; the file could be refused for a number of other reasons. My problem is to be able to receive the response sent by the server.

Comment: hmmm.. so if you try to read the response like so:  var stream = response.GetResponseStream() will you get an instant error?

Comment: I can't call `response.GetResponseStream()`, because I don't have a response at all... *that* is my problem, as stated in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I am experience a pretty similar problem currently also with Tomcat and a Java client. The Tomcat REST service sends a HTTP returncode with response body before reading the whole request body. The client however fails with IOException. I inserted a HTTP Proxy on the client to sniff the protocol and actually the HTTP response is sent to the client eventually. Most likly the Tomcat closed the request input stream before sending the response.

One solution is to use a different HTTP server like Jetty which does not have this problem. The other solution is a add a Apache HTTP server with AJP in front of Tomcat. Apache HTTP server has a different handling of streams and with that the problem goes away.